# C++ tuning / optimization

Tags: c++, optimization, performance

I read on this page http://www.theregister.co.uk/2011/06/03/google_paper_on_cplusplus_java_scala_go/ the following:

C++ offers the fastest runtime of the four languages. But, the paper says, it also requires more extensive "tuning efforts, many of which were done at a level of sophistication that would not be available to the average programmer."

I am a big C++ fan and obviously still learning. My question is what do they mean by 'tuning efforts' ? Do they refer to compiler settings or just using sophisticated coding techniques ? Any examples would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you just read the paper yourself?

Comment: @Benjamin: thanks for the prod to read the paper; the tuning notes were better than I expected.

Comment: @sarnold Tuning notes were rather disappointing: the first engineer who noticed that hash set is faster and figured out the right key to use with it got the performance up by 45%! Another engineer coded an alternative for tree set for 10%, the rest of them got 2..3 percent here and there for a lot more work! The moral of the story: learn your data structures :)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Not everyone will report that their improvements were only .5% -- and to get a detailed list of them all is certainly nice. Perhaps the initial version should have been written with better datastructures in the first place but iteration towards the goal is the norm.... :)

Answer (score 0):

From my experiences with these languages, I would say that it is referring to process of compiling and linking. I know that when I need to compile a program that uses many libraries in C++ or Java, it is requires many less arguments to the compiler when you use java than when you use C++. I haven't used Go or Scala for large projects so I cannot make a fair comparison for these. Also with C++, using pointers does require a lot of tuning if you will. It can get very complicated very fast when you start to use complex data types in C++. This may not at all help, but from my experiences that is what I know.

I also prefer C++. I just never can settle with the idea of an interpreted language that is offered in Java, as I said before I haven't used Scala or Go enough yet to get a fair report. But that is all I know in regards to "tuning efforts".

EDIT:

Sorry, I should have done my research, the tuning that the paper is referring to is just modifications of the original benchmark program, as disused in the comments of the original question.

Comment: Haha, sorry. Yes, JITed. It just doesn't sit right.